# Regex for string has condition before and after string

Tags: java, regex

I want to create regex match with string has before is `" "` or `"."` and use it in `replaceAll` in Java.

Example:

```
LLS.LLS kLLS LLS
```

I use regex `\bLLS\b`.

The result I want this is `LLS`.

But if I want to find string `"/LLS"` the regex is failed.

Example: `\b/LLS\b`
Find in string: `BBA /LLS CCA`

Can you help me to find a regex?
Thanks

Comment: Thank you. I can try with regex is \b\/LLS\b but regex is failed. You can try on web: /regexr.com

Comment: Please show the whole code. I believe you are building the regex pattern dynamically, right? Or do you put the regex patterns manually into code?

Comment: Please update the question with the relevant code.

Comment: This is regex and I will use it in my code. The answer for it is comment below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead and lookbehind to assert what is on the left and rigt is either a space or a dot in a characters class.:

```
(?<=[ .])/?LLS(?=[ .])
```

In Java:

```
String regex = "(?<=[ .])/?LLS(?=[ .])";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KX4C22/1)

Comment: Wonderful. It match all. But if I have a string only "/LLS" it dont match.
Can you help me ? Thanks!

Comment: I understand! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the first \b, you don't need to set a word boundary at the beginning

```
\/LLS\b
```

You can also make the / optional with ? to match both LLS or /LLS like so

```
\/?LLS\b
```

Here is an example https://regexr.com/48p5e

Comment: Thank you very much. I has tried but I has a problem. I want match if only /LLS
With your regex for string : BBA /LLS  E/LLS CCA. It match /LLS in E/LLS. I want match if /LLS has before and after is " " or "."